# How to correct this error? usemin not found

Tags: node.js, web-deployment, web-development-server, web-frontend, npm-scripts

I tried to run `npm run build` after installing rimraf,copyfiles,imagemin, usemin-cli, cssmin, uglifyjs and htmlmin. And then editing package.json file.
But I got the error

> sh: 1: usemin: not found

Here is my Package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a website for Ristorante Con Fusion",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:all",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "scss": "npx node-sass -o css/ css/",
    "watch:scss": "npx onchange 'css/*.scss' -- npm run scss",
    "watch:all": "concurrently 'npm run watch:scss' 'npm run lite'",
    "clean": "node_modules/rimraf/bin.js dist",
    "copyfonts": "copyfiles -f node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* dist/fonts",
    "imagemin": "imagemin img/* --out-dir='dist/img'",
    "usemin": "usemin contactus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/contactus.html && usemin aboutus.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/aboutus.html && usemin index.html -d dist --htmlmin -o dist/index.html",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run copyfonts && npm run imagemin && npm run usemin"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssmin": "^0.4.3",
    "htmlmin": "0.0.7",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "onchange": "^3.3.0",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "usemin-cli": "^0.5.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }
}
```

Tried Google, But Didn't found anything. I am using ubuntu

Comment: Try running `npm install` that will add all the packages from your package.json file. It looks like you haven't installed `usemin` which is different to `usemin-cli` which you have installed

Comment: Tried, Didn't worked.

Comment: Oh, I misread, I thought I saw `usemin` as a separate package to `usemin-cli`. Tricky one, have you tried renaming your script from `usemin` to something else, it might be an issue with conflicting with a package name?

Comment: Yes, I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I think npm is not able to read the path.

I added the path

> node_modules/.bin/usemin

In Place of usemin in the script above.

It Worked.

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem with the usemin-cli version, **upgrade to version 0.6.0**, I'm doing the same course and it works